# Not able to add child to existing child in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, playlist

I am creating a playlist app where every playlist has a unique key and have 2 child elements playlistId and playlist name. I want to add songs as a child under the playlist name.

**Like this:**

[image]

But this is what I am getting instead:

[image]

My code which brings the above-unwanted error prone result is -

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("a44f757c1f96ac85");

 public void saveSongsToPlayList(View view){
            try {
                String song = "Song";
               databaseReference.child(playListId).child(playListName)
                    .child("New song").child(song).setValue(song);
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

I don't think that I need to use the data snapshot for such a simple task. Or am I wrong?

Comment: What is the expeted result? song1, song2 are objects or properties? Can be please more specific? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Alex Mamo what Rajat Mittal suggested was right. And yes Song1, Song2 etc. were objects of their own. So I had to create a separate Song class with its id and songname  properties. Solved the previous issue. Please take a look at this new issue posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900674/not-able-to-remove-image-view-from-from-last-item-clicked-in-arrayadapter-textvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
     public void saveSongsToPlayList(View view){
                try {
                   Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://your-firebase-id.com").child("a44f757c1f96ac85").child("LZIZ......").child("playListName").child("NewSong")  
                   Firebase song1 = firebase.child("song")
                   song1.setValue("link to song or whatever")
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Comment: Your suggestion still adds child under -LZIZh8bE-jEtuRRBjcF which is the root. What I want is, to add child under the playListName which is an existing child of -LZIZh8bE-jEtuRRBjcF. So no your suggestion not working!!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add one child. Try now

Comment: Yes @Raj Mittal you were correct in your suggestion. Got the thing working. Accepted your answer. Have a new problem now. Posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900674/not-able-to-remove-image-view-from-from-last-item-clicked-in-arrayadapter-textvi

Comment: I am glad it worked. Please upvote the answer too so that other people will get the correct information. Thank You